# WP get_the_excerpt(); Read More points wrong link

Tags: php, wordpress

The "Read More" link that is outpouted in get_the_excerpt(); links to the correct post for excerpts on other templates, but in the code below (on a different template) the "Read More" link points to the page the user is currently on and not the post's permalink. I've seen other people post the same issue on other forums, but they were all closed before there was a resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach($pr_content as $ID) {
                $post_temp = $post;
                setup_postdata(get_post($ID));
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                $post = $post_temp;
                echo '<article>';
                echo '<h4><a href="'.get_the_permalink($ID).'">'.get_the_title($ID).'</a></h4>';
                echo $excerpt;
                echo '</article>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `get_the_permalink($ID)` to `get_permalink($ID)`

Comment: I gave that a shot, but the "read more" URL still points to the current page :(

Comment: how is `$pr_content` being populated?

Answer (score 0):

you not put $ID , Because $ID is not post id

so you must put `<?php get_the_ID(); ?>`

so your code is like that

```
foreach($pr_content as $ID) {
                $post_temp = $post;
                setup_postdata(get_post($ID));
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                $post = $post_temp;
                echo '<article>';
                echo '<h4><a href="'.get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()).'">'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'</a></h4>';
                echo $excerpt;
                echo '</article>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the way I was pulling the array. Thanks for your feedback. This approach resolved the issue.

```
if($pr_content) {
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post__in'          => $pr_content,
        'post_status'       => 'any',
    ));

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <article>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```